# Merge generic properties to class

Tags: typescript

I have a class `Aggregate<T>` like this:

```
class Aggregate<T> {
  data!: T
  constructor() {
    
  }
}
type Customer =  {companyName:string}

const customer = new Aggregate<Customer>()
customer.data.companyName = 'Some Corp.'
```

Is it possible to not need the `data` property of type `T` but instead "merge" all properties of `T` with the properties of `Aggregate<T>`?

So I would like to end up with

```
const customer = new Aggregate<Customer>()
customer.companyName = 'Some Corp.'
```

Comment: How doesn't the code above give you an error about `'companyName' of undefined`?

Comment: `const mkAggregate = <T>(): Aggregate<T> & T => new Aggregate<T>() as Aggregate<T> & T` but I'm not sure how this would work at runtime… What if you do `customer.companyName.toLowerCase()` without `companyName` being initialised? How do you plan to initialise these properties safely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default classes declarations can't do this. You can massage the class definition type with an assertion:

```
class AggregateImpl {
  constructor(data: unknown) {
    Object.assign(this, data)
  }
}
type Customer =  {companyName:string}
const Aggregate = AggregateImpl as new <T>(data?: T) => AggregateImpl & T

const customer = new Aggregate<Customer>()
customer.companyName = 'Some Corp.'
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCDm8BOBTeYAuKCSBbADiNAN4BQ00wA9gHYQZICuwGVSAFACaZgBc0jGgGsaVAO40AlCXIVoAeQBGAKxQsAdJAgBLeDXYYAFtogAaaNwxhJsgL6l7GAJ74U0AMKN6VXCiTQAXgpiagIwGicAOTBfXnokbRp4e2o6DDhEVHQsQIzkNEwcAiJIaBoUMWgAHgAVAD4uHgB+fhrpALq8rMK8QmgAMmga0lJU+kovVl9-IPLKhHzslCrPb2mGm2BJnz91UPxwqJi3IIByAGUdjzZ8dVOR0gB6R+hIqnT5IVHwKGgAcRQ5QSwAAIn5tAA3FCcWqdFAADywNE4MAW3SwsJkDhGzwUX1AWmgYISUM40ARSJRXQKGNWUz8nTIFAcQA)

Although this will not play well with inheritance in all cases:

```
// Not Ok
class GenericDerived<T> extends Aggregate<T> {

}

// Ok
class Derived extends Aggregate<Customer> {
  
}
```

Also accessing the properties from inside the class isn't possible without a type assertion (`(this as any)['whatever']`). Adding an index signature is also possible but you would need to remove it in the return type of `Aggregate` otherwise you loose all type safety.